# Seaborn presents all the labels on the X axis

Tags: python, pandas, label, seaborn

I am plotting a box graph distribution of my Y variable over some key countries.

```
    ersa = pd.read_excel(r'data.xlsx')
    country = ['Bangladesh', 'China', 'Viet Nam', 'India', 'Cambodia', 
  'Malaysia']
    ersa_source = ersa[ersa['Country'].isin(country)]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(11, 11.27)
    sns.set_style('white')
    pal = sns.color_palette('Paired')
    b = sns.boxplot(x='Country', y=Y,
                 data= ersa_source, width=0.5, palette= pal)
    b =sns.stripplot(x='Country', y=Y, 
                        data = ersa_source, 
                        jitter=True, 
                        linewidth = 1, 
                        alpha=0.6,  dodge=True,
                        palette = pal)
     b= sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
     ax.set_title('Title', fontsize = 20)
     ax.set_xlabel('Country', fontsize = 15)
     ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize = 15)
```

Unfortunately, the X-axis is ticked with all the countries (approx.100), rather than just the 6 selected countries.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What is `Y` when you reference it in the plots? Do you mean `'Y'` or is it some variable you defined elsewhere?

Comment: Can you check if ersa_source successfully filtered the countries? Something like: `ersa_source['Country'].unique()`

Comment: I swear I changed nothing, but it seems now is all working. Sorry for wasting your time!